# Scan video for text string?

Tags: youtube

My goal is to find the title screen from a movie trailer. I need a service where I can search a video for a string, then return the frame with that string. Pretty obscure, does anything like this exist?

e.g. for this movie, I'd scan for "Sausage Party" and retrieve this frame:

[image]

Edit: I found the [cloudsight api](http://www.cloudsightapi.com/) which would actually work except cost is prohibitive @ $.04 per call assuming I need to split the video into 1s intervals and scan every image (at least 60 calls per video).

Answer (score 3):

No exact service that I can find, but you could attempt to do this yourself...

```
ffmpeg -i sausage_party.mp4 -r 1 %04d.png
/usr/local/bin/parallel --no-notice -j 8 \
  /usr/local/bin/tesseract -psm 6 -l eng {} {.} \
  ::: *.png
```

This extracts one frame a second from the video file, and then uses tesseract to extract the text via OCR into files of the same name as the image frame (eg. `0135.txt`. However your results are going to vary massively depending on the font used and the quality of the video file.

You'd probably find it cheaper/easier to use something like [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) , especially since the OCR is going to have a hard time doing this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be implementing this service by yourself using the Scene Text Detection and Recognition module in OpenCV (docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/text.html). You can take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvBH5aakt_A) to get an idea of how such a system would operate. As pointed out above the accuracy would depend on the font used in the movie titles, the quality of the video files, and the OCR.

OpenCV relies on Tesseract as the underlying OCR but, alternatively, you could use the text detection and localization functions (docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html) in OpenCV to find text areas in the image and then employ a different OCR to perform the recognition. The text detection and localization stage can be done [very quickly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2TbchgVdeA) thus achieving real time performance would be mostly a matter of picking a fast OCR.